# How to show RadListView on iOS

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I have the following code:

```
<GridLayout row="7" col="0" colSpan="3" rows="*" cols="*">
     <RadListView [items]="sourcesOptions" height="100%">
           <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
                 <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
                       <Switch [checked]="true" class="switch"></Switch>
                       <Label [text]="item.label" textWrap="true" marginTop="15"></Label>
                 </StackLayout>
           </ng-template>
           <ListViewGridLayout tkListViewLayout itemHeight="200" scrollDirection="Vertical" spanCount="2"></ListViewGridLayout>
     </RadListView>
</GridLayout>
```

It is working on Android, but on iOS it isn't showing anything.

**Note**

I don't know if this can be related to the issue, but I get the items from a rest service.

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Playground of the above code is working as expected https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=Es3fBf

Comment: Check if you have 8 rows in the parent GridLayout (`row="7" col="0"`)

Comment: @NickIliev I checked the playground example, and it works. I don't know if it happens because I get the items from a rest service. And yes, I have 8 rows in the parent grid, it is working on Android correctly

Comment: `it happens because I get the items from a rest service` - that's it.. on iOS when the  items are coming async you need to set a height of the item template (using `itemHeight` - see here https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/NativeScript/ListView/item-layouts#using-listviewlinearlayout)

Comment: Or directly asssign height for the parent layout of youtr item template (in your case teh `StackLayout`)

Comment: @NickIliev  You gave me the idea of how to fix it, the problem was with the height of the parent layout of the RadListView (The GridLayout). I published an answer with the code that fixed my issue. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the height when the items are async, in that case I needed to set the height manually to the parent layout of the RadListView component (The GridLayout in my case).

It didn't work if I set a height with percentage (100%), it had to be a fixed number, it was very inconvenient because the number of items are not always the same, so I created a function to set the height according with number of items received.

This is the code that fixed the issue:

```
<GridLayout row="7" col="0" colSpan="3" rows="*" cols="*" [height]="setHeight()">
     <RadListView [items]="sourcesOptions">
          <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
               <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
                    <Switch [checked]="true" class="switch"></Switch>
                    <Label [text]="item.label" textWrap="true" marginTop="15"></Label>
               </StackLayout>
          </ng-template>
          <ListViewGridLayout tkListViewLayout itemHeight="70" scrollDirection="Vertical" spanCount="2"></ListViewGridLayout>
     </RadListView>
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a height value on the RLV component like `height="100%"` so it fills the parent. iOS doesn't do auto layouts the same android does, that's why you run into this :)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided a `rows` or `columns` definition for your `GridLayout`. The `RadListView` will likely show up if you do:

```
<GridLayout row="7" col="0" colSpan="3" rows="*" columns="*">
```

Comment: Expanding on this,  based on the Qs markup you could even use a StackLayout here and drop the Grid.

Comment: Ian and @Brad I edited the questions with the changes you suggested me, but it stills showing nothing. I tried the StackLayout suggestion of Brad with the same result

Comment: Not exactly what I said tho  - put the height on the RLV not the parent. This way iOS will say "oh, make this listview 100% of the parent which is this grid" 